# Getting user level demographics from BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-analytics, google-bigquery

I have a basic question regarding Google analytics and bigquery.
In searching for this online I haven't seen a straight answer.

If I have a blog with user id's 1,2,3...
I also have google analytics running on my site picking up the utms param's etc.

When I log into google analytics I can see it has demographic breakdown of my users(sex, age), it also has interests, which is what I'm really interested in.

I heard that I can pull all this underlying data from bigquery if I have a premium account.

If that bigquery connection is made, can I run a query like?

```
select blog_user_id, 
    interest_name, 
    sum(interest_spend) as spend, 
    sum(interest_num_impressions) as lvl_interest
        from bigquery bg
            left join blog_user_base bl on bl.cookies=bg.cookies
group by 1,2
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the schema exported from Google Analytics to Google BigQuery:

https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/3437719?hl=en

It doesn't seem to have the 'interest' column right now - though the list of variables increase regularly by customers requests. Variables like these are trickier as they are not part of regular logs - so they might not be surfaceable on the granular level.

Comment: Thanks Felipe for that info. I have seen this already, however, it doesn't clarify if the dataset can be queried at a common cookie level so that I can populate my user base with the google dimensions

Comment: Not sure if this solves your case, but: With Analytics you can have custom variables where you could log your user ids and later join them with other datasets in BigQuery

Comment: Hi Felipe, Are you saying that this type of matching is possible? So would I pass the user id into my url then have that in the bigquery table as a custom field. So the join above would be altered too 'code' on bl.custom_field = bg.user_id 'code'

Comment: @user2331566 Felipe says that there is no User Interest column available to perform your query. Before thinking of the join, you need to have data for it, but it's not available yet. For a moment think and switch your focus to what data is available and not to the join.

Comment: @Pentium10 thanks for voicing Felipe's opinion for him, but I was asking Felipe a question on his last comment.